# Establishing a communication between Java program and MySQL database

Tags: java, php, mysql, database, jdbc

I am having Java program and MySQL database running on the remote server. Now what I want is to establish a communication and to be able to execute queries (select, insert, delete, update) from java program to make effect in the database. I do know that there is a library (JDBC MySQL connector) that allows me to connect my Java program with the database. I also know it is possible to execute queries right from the Java program using MySQL JDBC interface. My question is, however, if this "kind" of communication with the database stored on the remote server is safe enough. I have also read there is an option of using PHP/Pearl to do that. So my question is:

What is the best option/solution in establishing a connection between Java program and the MySQL database running on the remote server over the internet?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, however, if this "kind" of communication with the database stored on the remote server is safe enough.

Modulo the question of what you really mean by "safe enough", the answer *could* be Yes ... if you take reasonable precautions.  For example:

- use `PreparedStatement` and query parameters to avoid problems with SQL injection<sup>1</sup>
- if possible, use a properly secured private network (for example a VPN) for java <-> database traffic
- if you can't secure the network, use SSL; e.g. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html
- secure your database accounts and your authentication credentials.

<sup>1 - This deals with a different mode of "attack" ... but it is actually a common.</sup>

---

You also need to balance your need for remote database access against your security and risk management.  For instance, if the potential consequences of a security breach are dire, then maybe you shouldn't even *contemplate* doing database access over the internet.

---

> What is the best option/solution in establishing a connection between Java program and the MySQL database running on the remote server over the internet?

I don't think we can answer that.

Comment: VPN tunnel comes to mind though, regarding that last off-topic question. Perhaps it is not the best, but it is certainly a good idea IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your database only accepts php-scripts from the same server for security reasons.
A possibility is:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882135/how-to-send-data-from-java-applet-to-php-to-mysql-and-read-data-from-mysql-to-ph